# Web: How can I design a div container that the normal user knows that it is draggable?

Tags: asp.net, draggable, user-experience

i have made in my asp.net applictation a small `div` container, which is `draggable` (in this way: [Make jQuery-ui draggable handle cover entire page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956618/make-jquery-ui-draggable-handle-cover-entire-page)).

I want to make clear, that the normal user knows instinctively, that he/she can drag this container around the page.

I have set the cursor via CSS to `cursor: move;`.
But with this solution the user only gains the knowledge while moving the mouse over the small container.

How can I make sure, the user knows from the beginning, that this small div is draggable?

Comment: Simple put a message "drag with mouse" over the div title

Comment: why not put a label stating that the section is draggable, you can use a semi-transparent labels and hide it at mouse hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [image] this kind of image on div which is draggable. This image will always visible so user can get to know easily this div is draggalbe and of course by the ***css*** you can put it center over the div. and image will type of png so it will not look ugly and you can apply transparency that hand image so contant of the div can visible even image is over the div.

and yes there are other suggestion also given by @Prabhavith and @Matt Lowe..you can also work around with that.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've seen this done that makes any sense to me is to have a faintly written message with the word "Drag" and arrows pointing through the four ordinals centered in the div.

Answer (score 1):

Like the image in the linked question, you can make your draggable div look more like a traditional desktop window. Users are used to dragging around windows that have a title bar across the top and minimize,mazimize, and close buttons, and a border with an optional bevel. Approximating this style will help communicate draggability.

Likewise, having the border around the div grow darker or highlight will help communicate draggability as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this site http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/DragPanel/DragPanel.aspx